# Passing Class Reference over Interface

Tags: vb.net, class, interface

I'm sorry for editing but I got the feeling like my question was not specific enough.

I have a Host Application, a Interface.dll and a Plugin.dll. Within my Host Application I'm globally using a Instance of a class.

However: My Plugin.dll (which implements my iInterface form the Interface.dll) needs to have access to that specific instance of my class in the Host Application.

By having my Functions names within the interface, I can access those functions in the plugin from the host application, but how can I access the global class instance from the plugin?

I cannot write

```
Public Interface IPlugin

    Sub SetInstance(ByRef MyClassInstance As MyClass)

End Interface
```

But this es exactly what I want to do...

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You want implementations of the interface to serve as container for instances of `MyClass`? Does `CreateInstance()` have anything to do with that instance you want to pass? Otherwise, can't you make `MyClass` implement `IInterface`?

Comment: The plugin is not interested in MyClass, it just wants a reference of the interface type.  Nor does it know anything about MyClass, that's a type that lives in a different assembly that the plugin doesn't know about.  So your "ClassInstance" field needs to be of type IInterface instead.

Comment: @Hans: Hmm.. sounds like MyClass has to Implement iInterface instead of iInterface has to implement MyClass?

Comment: @Mapper: I don't see the point. If MyClass implements the iPlugin Interface, then I'll get a lot of members which should not be withhin of MyClass. And yes, ClassInstance was just an example. Don't care about it.

Comment: @AllDayPiano: In that case, my first question applies: You want implementations of `IPlugin` to serve as a container for an instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: @Mapper: What I want is pretty simple. I want my Plugin (which implements the IPlugin Interface Class) to act like a usual class object within the same namespace as the host application. My host application is meant to load the Plugin.dll while running. After having loaded the plugin the plugin itself must set a couple of properties (that are contained in an instance of a class that is used by the main application). If the plugin where within the host project, I would simply access "Me.MyCassInstance.MyClassProperty = ...". I hope you understand my aim.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement the class from the host application within an interface. The only way would be referencing as object which will cause plenty of other problems.

Solution was to export the common classes into a own library (.dll) and instantiate this library to both - the host application and the plugin and in the interface.

Now passing the reference is possible without any problems as if all the different code parts were within the same namespace.

Thank you guys for your help.